# Grails testing a closure on a mocked object

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

Hi i have the following simple function:

```
  public static writeToFile(File productsFile,Param param) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream)getOutputStream(Param param)
        productsFile.withDataOutputStream {stream ->
            outputStream.writeTo(stream)
        }
        return productsFile
    }
```

what would be the best way to make a unit test on it? Keep in mind that this function gets a file and i don't think its a good idea Create a file for a unit test so probably i would like to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no need to mock a File cause there is no functionality (in the File object) that you need to control at while the unit tests run.

The main functionality you can check is the writing to the file, that is why there is no necessity to create a Mock for the File.

The test should check the different Params and different types of Params you pass to the function.
For example: null, [ ], " ", Date, regularString, numbers etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, lets say that getOutputStream(Param param) is tested. Could you put some pseudocode in your answer so i can understand your point.